# C# Deserialization Error

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I'm working with Visual C# Express and I have two projects, one is named mapEditor and the second is named Game.
my problem is that I'm serializing an object to a file in mapEditor and I want to deserialize that object in the Game project.
I'm getting the exact same class(of the object I'm serializing) in both projects and it only deserializes in mapEditor.
please please give a solution i've been stuck on this for months.

thanks :)

Comment: Without more and specific details, you will be stuck for a few more years.

Comment: You'll have to tell us a bit more than that!

Comment: Do you get an exception? What kind? What's the message? What code is causing it? Have you stepped through it in the debugger? [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the namespaces of the two projects differ, so this is why it isn't working.

Try making a dynamic link library which contains that class, and use the same library in both projects. This way, you can also modify the class in one project, it will be modified automatically in the second project.

### How to create a dynamic link library:

1. Open the new project window in Visual Studio
2. Select the project type *Class Library*
3. Make sure the project is added to the current solution, and accept
4. Add your classes in the newly created project, make sure they are `public`
5. Add a reference to the library project in all other projects.

Comment: they both have the namespace of Game, and i'm not getting an error because before i did anything in the Game project i first wrote an if statement to check if the object i'm serializing to is not null so i have three lines down: ` WorldMap world = loadMap("map.dat"); if(world!=null) Console.WriteLine("Success"); else Console.WriteLine("Fail"); `

Comment: Even though the namespaces may be the same, they are classes from 2 different projects, so maybe that's why it is not working. You should create a dynamic link library with that class that is shared between the 2 projects.

Comment: how do i do that? p.s. i opened the serialized file with a hex editor and i saw at the top written @ mapEditor so i tried to change it to @ Game through the hex editor but it just made the file unusable, i can show you my code if it will help

Comment: That won't be necessary. In Visual Studio, create a new project (make sure it's in the same solution), and in project type select Class Library. Put the class in that project, and make sure it's public. Next, add a reference in all the other projects to the library project.

Comment: I modified the answer for completeness sake.